# react-native-gesture-handler module was not found

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-native-gesture-handler

For some reason, my project does not recognize the installation of `react-native-gesture-handler`. The issue only appears when testing on Android devices and emulators.

The module is added to the `package.json` as `"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",`.

The full error description:

```
react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..).

For installation instructions, please refer to https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation
```

I have tried following:

- Followed the installation guide here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation
- Restartet Metro
- Tried `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`
- Cleaned Gradles
- Deleted and reinstalled node_modules
- Reinstalled the project on devices

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue!

Even though the manual linking is deprecated in RN 0.60<, I ran a `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler` and this revealed that no `MainApplication.java`-file was found following the path in Android-folder. I looked at the path and discovered that the path was not equal to my folder structure. Yesterday I renamed the project from package com.myAppName to com.myAppName.app hence the `MainApplication.java`-file is now expected to be found at  `.../android/app/src/main/java/com/myAppName/app/MainApplication.java` instead of `.../android/app/src/main/java/com/myAppName/MainApplication.java`. So I created an `app`-folder and put the `MainApplication.java` and `MainActivity.java` in there, rebuilt the project and now it's running again.

This was not an issue because of the `react-native-gesture-handler` module but because of a misconfiguration in the project.